# Can't bind parameter 'log' to type TraceWriter when running Azure function template locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I met an issue when using Azure function.

I create a Azure Functions v1(.Net Framework) Http Trigger template in VS. But when I try to run it directly, exceptions thrown.
[image: my exception here]

I am using latest version of VS(15.6.7) and Azure Functions and Web Job tools(15.0.40502.0).

When I run it first time, no prompt for installation of anything, it runs on 1.0.10 Azure Function CLI. After I restart my VS and try to run it again, VS asks to download 1.0.12.1 Function CLI. The download seems failed as I still see 1.0.10 on the tile of window. The exception remains all the time.

Any idea? It doesn't make sense since I just try to run a template.

Comment: Sounds like reference version conflict. Have you changed any references?

Comment: Could you show your detailed version of your azure function and webjob tools? Here is a similar [case](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/744), you could refer to it.

Comment: Have you got any prompt that you need to install 1.0.12.1 function core tools? And have you successfully installed it? You can see your core tool version on the title of window where you got your screenshot, looks like`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionTools\Releases\version\cli\Func.exe`.

Comment: @Mikhail no, it's a pure http trigger template.

Comment: @JoeyCai, it's 15.0.40502.0.

Comment: @JerryLiu no prompt, it runs on 1.0.10 version core tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have updated my question with some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is shown in your screenshot.

> Starting Host(...,Version=1.0.11232.0)

It means your function Cli is **1.0.4** other than **1.0.10** actually, here's [release note of 1.0.4](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/1.0.4). After tests, find that old version does cause this exception. This version issue roots in failing to download latest Azure Function Core Tools trough VS.

**Update for official solution**

[Handle downloading problem of Azure Function Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio). Try the first option to download using VS again, if it still fails, use the second option, PS scripts.

---

**Below is the original solution, similar to the first and third official option, just ignore it**

**More Details**

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools is updated to `15.0.40502.0` recently and mechanism of using local function Cli is also changed. [Release Notes](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md).

> Tools now consume a feed which keeps templates, build tools, and the runtime up to date whenever there is a change made in the service.

The first time we create an Azure function after this update, we can see the tip on the dialog `Making sure all templates are up to date...`. It means VS is downloading necessary cli and templates to this folder `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools`.

[image]
After a while, we can see the tip changes as

[image]

If we don't wait the downloading to complete and create project directly, it will prompt that VS is downloading `1.0.12.1` Cli. And everything should work fine after that.

As for your problem, I reproduce it once due to slow network. It fails to download those files and tries to use old version cli downloaded by VS before.

**Solution**

I recommend you to delete `AzureFunctionsTools` folder and restart your VS to download it again.

If it still fails to download, you can download it manually.
You can find download link of cli, itemTemplates and projectTemplates in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\feed.json`.

And the folder structure in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.0.12.1` is like this

```
cli
--func.exe
....
templates
--ItemTemplates.nupkg
--ProjectTemplates.nupkg
manifest.json
```

Content of manifest.json

```
{
  "ReleaseName": "1.0.12.1",
  "CliEntrypointPath":"C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\1.0.12.1\\cli\\func.exe",
  "TemplatesDirectory": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\1.0.12.1\\templates",
  "FunctionsExtensionVersion": "~1",
  "SdkPackageVersion": "1.0.13"
}
```

Comment: I remove the folder and wait the download to finish. Finally it works, thanks for your time!

Comment: Your answer saved my time. I remove the folder, but still failed to download it. So i manually download the relevant files and put them into the folder 1.6.0. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @CrazyCrab Glad it worked, now there are [official steps](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio) to handle this downloading problem.  With the second option,  automation scripts, we don't need manual work anymore.